# How to update texts for TimePicker's labels

Tags: flutter, dart

When call `showTimePicker` like this

```dart
showTimePicker(
    initialTime: initialTime, // 23:59
    context: context,
    builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
        child: child,
        );
    },
);
```

we have standard view

[image]

I want to translate text to other language (it is Russian in this case). I have
some fields to set texts

```dart
showTimePicker(
    initialTime: initialTime,
    context: context,
    cancelText: 'Отмена',   // <--
    confirmText: 'Принять', // <--
    builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
            child: child,
        );
    },
);
```

After that we get such result

[image]

But I cant change `Hour`, `Minute`, `Enter time` & etc.

**How to update** them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets watch [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart)

[Hour label](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart#L1439)

```dart
Text(
    MaterialLocalizations.of(context).timePickerHourLabel,
    style: theme.textTheme.caption,
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

[Minute label](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart#L1468)

```dart
Text(
    MaterialLocalizations.of(context).timePickerMinuteLabel,
    style: theme.textTheme.caption,
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

As we see, texts are taken from [localizations](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_localizations.dart#L792)' context.

So we need to override these values. We can implement [MaterialLocalizations](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_localizations.dart#L88) or inherit [DefaultMaterialLocalizations](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_localizations.dart#L539)

I choose second variant, because it is shorter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppMaterialLocalization extends DefaultMaterialLocalizations {

  const AppMaterialLocalization();

  @override
  String get invalidTimeLabel => 'Некорректное время';

  @override
  String get timePickerDialHelpText => 'Выберите время';

  @override
  String get timePickerHourLabel => 'Часы';

  @override
  String get timePickerInputHelpText => 'Введите время';

  @override
  String get timePickerMinuteLabel => 'Минуты';


  static Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture<MaterialLocalizations>(const AppMaterialLocalization());
  }

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> delegate = _AppMaterialLocalizationsDelegate();
}

class _AppMaterialLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const _AppMaterialLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'ru'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    return AppMaterialLocalization();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> old) =>
      false;
}
```

**WARNING!**

It is important to set `MaterialLocalizations` generic for delegate.

At last but not least we set localizations' config for app

```dart
MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
        AppMaterialLocalization.delegate
    ],
    ...
```

[image]